# how to change tymon jwt authentication to use member model instead of user model in laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, jwt, laravel-5.6

In my project I have users and members tables and eloquent models.
I'm going to use jwt authentication in members table and I changed corresponding config files, but still it goes to User model.

Here is `config/auth.php` :

```
return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Defaults
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
| reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
| as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
|
*/

'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Guards
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
| Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
| here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| Supported: "session", "token"
|
*/

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'members',
    ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| User Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
| sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
| be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
|
| Supported: "database", "eloquent"
|
*/

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    'members' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => \App\Models\Member::class
    ]

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Resetting Passwords
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
| than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
| separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
|
| The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
| considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
| they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
|
*/

'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
],
];
```

And here is `config/jwt.php`:

```
return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| JWT Authentication Secret
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Don't forget to set this, as it will be used to sign your tokens.
| A helper command is provided for this: `php artisan jwt:generate`
|
*/

'secret' => env('JWT_SECRET', 'changeme'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| JWT time to live
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Specify the length of time (in minutes) that the token will be valid for.
| Defaults to 1 hour
|
*/

'ttl' => 60,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Refresh time to live
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Specify the length of time (in minutes) that the token can be refreshed
| within. I.E. The user can refresh their token within a 2 week window of
| the original token being created until they must re-authenticate.
| Defaults to 2 weeks
|
*/

'refresh_ttl' => 20160,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| JWT hashing algorithm
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Specify the hashing algorithm that will be used to sign the token.
|
| See here: https://github.com/namshi/jose/tree/2.2.0/src/Namshi/JOSE/Signer
| for possible values
|
*/

'algo' => 'HS256',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| User Model namespace
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Specify the full namespace to your User model.
| e.g. 'Acme\Entities\User'
|
*/

'user' => 'App\Models\Member',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| User identifier
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Specify a unique property of the user that will be added as the 'sub'
| claim of the token payload.
|
*/

'identifier' => 'id',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Required Claims
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Specify the required claims that must exist in any token.
| A TokenInvalidException will be thrown if any of these claims are not
| present in the payload.
|
*/

'required_claims' => ['iss', 'iat', 'exp', 'nbf', 'sub', 'jti'],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Blacklist Enabled
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| In order to invalidate tokens, you must have the blacklist enabled.
| If you do not want or need this functionality, then set this to false.
|
*/

'blacklist_enabled' => env('JWT_BLACKLIST_ENABLED', true),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Specify the various providers used throughout the package.
|
*/

'providers' => [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Provider
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Specify the provider that is used to find the user based
    | on the subject claim
    |
    */

    'user' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\User\EloquentUserAdapter',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | JWT Provider
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Specify the provider that is used to create and decode the tokens.
    |
    */

    'jwt' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWT\NamshiAdapter',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Provider
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Specify the provider that is used to authenticate users.
    |
    */

    'auth' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\Auth\IlluminateAuthAdapter',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Storage Provider
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Specify the provider that is used to store tokens in the blacklist
    |
    */

    'storage' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\Storage\IlluminateCacheAdapter',

],

];
```

When I try to use `JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)` it returns error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'mobile' in
>   'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `mobile` =
>   98123456789 limit 1)

How could I fix this?

Comment: Any solutions friends?

Comment: Implement your own version of `Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\User\EloquentUserAdapter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I was looking at something like this because I have a web app with 2 tables one is **users** another is **clients**

I make web log in for user and api log in for clients

the second model need to extend like this:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Client extends Authenticatable
```

then in /config/auth.php

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'clients',
    ]
],
```

I changed the provider for api But you can add any guards you want then create a provider:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'clients' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Client::class,
    ],
]
```

And finally in the function you get the credential cause the guard you need

```
auth()->shouldUse('api');

$credentials = $request->only('email','password');
```